# Maven Eclipse-Aether: getLicence() method

Tags: java, maven, aether

I'm developing a maven-plugin to check dependencies' licenses, similar to [this one](https://github.com/mrice/license-check), but I can't found any API for that... what I would like to have is something like

```
String licence = artifact.getLicence();
```

mrice on that [license-check plugin](https://github.com/mrice/license-check) just try to find the .pom file of that artifact, read it, and try to find the `<license></license>`.

Do you know how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `org.apache.maven.model.License`. (See [api docs](http://maven.apache.org/archives/maven-1.x/reference/maven-model/3.0.2/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/License.html) for details).

Something like this:

```
try {
    Reader reader = new FileReader(pomXmlFile);
    Model model;
    try {
        final MavenXpp3Reader xpp3Reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
        model = xpp3Reader.read(reader);
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
    List<License> licenses = model.getLicenses();
} catch (XmlPullParserException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

*Note that many poms do not have a license.