# Get licenses of dependencies of a github project online

Tags: maven, github, dependencies, report, licensing

I'm currently building a website where I have a search bar which can search Github with your keyword. Once I select a repository from it, I want to be able to get a list of all the **licenses of the dependencies** used in the project.

I am current;y able to get a list of the dependencies. How do I get a list of their licenses too, without installing or running any additional softwares?

I started with the `project-info-reports:dependencies` command from maven which works beautifully, but then I realized I can't run this command when I select a repo on my website.

I then figured I could use the Github Licenses API for this task, but it turns out, it can give me the licenses of a repo, but not those of the dependencies used in it.

I'm planning on implementing it for as many projects as possible, but to start with, I chose Maven as it is one of the most common ones out there. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are the dependencies identified?

Comment: I have written a parser that can parse the pom file to get a list of the dependencies from any maven project on github. I'm using the MavenXpp3Reader to read the pom file

Comment: then you should be able to recusively fetch the dependencies of each protect. So basically you are rewriting this portion of Maven

Comment: Yeah that's true. But I'm trying to find a way to get the licenses for each of these dependencies. I came across this post on SO - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937525/maven-eclipse-aether-getlicence-method) where someone mentions using `org.apache.maven.model.License`. But this what the API says in its description - `The licenses listed for the project are that of the project itself, and not of dependencies.`

Comment: So fetch the dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot, I finally found out that there are at present no APIs provided by both Github and Maven to help you get the open source licenses of each dependency in pom file.

The only work around taht worked was building my own URL from the artifact ID, Group ID, and the version of the dependency  - and searching for the license on the Maven Repository website.